# submitting sitemaps with 2 different websites but content same

Tags: web, dns, sitemap, google-search-console

I have two domains running on the same server with the same IP (same content).

For example : In sitemap.xml there is example1.com is one website and method1.com,method2.com like that many pages will come.So can i use only one sitemap and include 2 websites or make different sitemaps.Give me a solution

Whatever iam working on 2nd url its affecting 1st url also

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use one sitemap.xml for two sites. According to [Sitemap Protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html):

> Also, all URLs in a Sitemap must be from a single host, such as www.example.com or store.example.com.

Comment: ok but home page url is in frameset and redirecting to another url.so the another url has many pages

Comment: In this case, a sitemap for 1st site should only contain home page URL, and the 2nd one should contain all of pages from another domain.

Comment: 2nd url contain many pages but two different website content is same

Comment: yes correct 2nd url contain many pages but home page is different url shall i innclude the homepage url in sitemap

Comment: No, you shouldn't, since home page cannot be a URL on different domain.

Comment: then what is the solution for this

Comment: I have generated 2nd site sitemap.xml Shall i include 1st site url in same sitemap because both website content is same.

Comment: No, you should not. Sitemap doesn't care of content at all, it's just defining URLs of the site's pages.

Comment: without including 1st site url in sitemap how search engines will find,because iam getting all details for 2nd site only.I need 1st site url must ranked in google

Comment: Search engines will find 1st site URLs from 1st site's sitemap.